# Interrupt triggers without button pressed what can i do?

Tags: gpio, python, interrupts

I have two buttons: a red and a green one and i want to measure how often each one gets pressed and i want to write into a csv file. The problem is even without me pressing the buttons the pi gets signals and i don't know where they come from. the only things attached are two leds to display which colour is pressed, two resistor and the buttons.

**EDIT:**

My wiring:

[image]

My code:

```
import csv
import time
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from datetime import datetime
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
Tic = 0
document = "/home/pi/Desktop/data.csv"
logfile = "/home/pi/Desktop/logfile.csv"
dirpath = os.getcwd()
print(dirpath)
def InterruptRed(channel):
    with open(document, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter = ",")
        data = list(reader)
    ifile = open(document, "r")
    reader = csv.reader(ifile, delimiter = ";")
    a = []
    for row in reader:
        a.append(row)
    print("Red")
    global CounterRed 
    CounterRed = int(a[0][0])
    CounterRed = CounterRed + 1
    print(CounterRed)
    rowoutr = [str(CounterRed)]
    rowoutg = [a[1][0]]
    with open(document, "w") as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter= ' ', lineterminator='\r\n')
        writer.writerow(rowoutr)
        writer.writerow(rowoutg)
    csvFile.close()
    rowoutlogred = ["red;"+str(datetime.now())]
    print(rowoutlogred)
    with open(logfile, "a") as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter= ' ', lineterminator='\r\n')
        writer.writerow(rowoutlogred)
    csvFile.close()

def InterruptGreen(channel):
    with open(document, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter = ",")
        data = list(reader)
    ifile = open(document, "r")
    reader = csv.reader(ifile, delimiter = ";")
    a = []
    for row in reader:
        a.append(row)
    print("Green")
    global CounterGreen
    CounterGreen = int(a[1][0])
    CounterGreen = CounterGreen + 1
    print(CounterGreen)
    rowoutg = [str(CounterGreen)]
    rowoutr = [a[0][0]]
    with open(document, "w") as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter= ' ', lineterminator='\r\n')
        writer.writerow(rowoutr)
        writer.writerow(rowoutg)
    csvFile.close()
    rowoutloggreen =["green;"+str(datetime.now())]
    print(rowoutloggreen)
    with open(logfile, "a") as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter = ' ',lineterminator='\r\n')
        writer.writerow(rowoutloggreen)
    csvFile.close()

GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(6, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.add_event_detect(5, GPIO.RISING, callback = InterruptRed, bouncetime = 500)
GPIO.add_event_detect(6, GPIO.RISING, callback = InterruptGreen, bouncetime = 500)

while True:
    Tic = Tic + 1
    #print(Tic)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Are those resistors you mention pull-ups/downs for the buttons?

Comment: You might want to try and reduce this to [an SSCCE](http://sscce.org/); it looks like it would not take very long but it could make all the difference debugging wise, and at the very least, someone else could run it and confirm it is not the code (meaning, its your wiring or a defect).

Comment: We need clear photos of the wiring.  It sounds like the GPIO are floating (Google floating gpio).

Comment: The resistors are only there for my leds and i edited the post

Comment: You should add pullup resistors to those gpios

Comment: i tried pull up and pull down resistors already nothing changed

Comment: get rid of the LEDs and the resistors